# Function composition with differing join ends

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to D $ are two functions. When does $g\circ f$ make sense?

My thinking: when $\operatorname{Im}(f)\subseteq C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. The function $g\circ f$ makes sense when and only when $f(A)\subset C$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course when *any* part of the image of $f$ is not within $C$ the mapping will not be possible.

So $f(A)\subseteq C$ is necessary for $g\circ f$ to be sensible.

---

Notice, this is not the same thing as requiring $B\subseteq C$, as the image *may not* be the entirety of $B$.